# Does the block contain the generation time of the block?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-go

Does the block contain the generation time of the block? How do I get it if it contains?
Where it is located?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually hyperledger Fabric don't have timestamp on Blocks

Below is a hyperledger Fabric Blockstructure.

There is a Issue to add that in future [FAB-15584](https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-15584)

[image: Hyperledger Fabric Block Structure]

Comment: But when I read the official fabric document, it said that the metadata part contains the block write time.https://i.stack.imgur.com/u964J.png

Comment: There isn't a block time, I inspected at a Block and the latest code version, the only timestamp is the channel header generated by the client to prevent replay attacks. This information is wrong, 
I will open a issue for that.
There is a issue to add timestamp at block header in future, https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-15584

Comment: A colegue did a fix in docs there is the PR https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/pull/378/files

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and hope to add block generation time in the next version. Thank you!